# Couldn't extract out the href values form the <a> tags using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BS4 for webpage scraping, and have the below `html` :

```
<a style="display:inline; position:relative;" href="

                                      /aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz">
                                Screenshot.docx                      </a>
```

Now how to get the value of the `href` using BS4, couldn't get. Can you help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {"style": "display:inline; position:relative;"}, href=True):
    href = a['href'].strip()
    href = "http://example.com" + href
print(href)

'http://example.com/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz'
```

The built in function `strip()` is very helpful here. :)

Comment: But I want only <a> having such properties `<a style="display:inline; position:relative;"` not the other <a> tags!

Comment: OK @VBSlover. In the future, specify __everything__ in your question.

Comment: sure I will Sorry for this time. I forgot to mention one thing,but don't think need to mentions at all Still mentioning here - `<a style="display:inline; position:relative;"` are closed in <td> .. </td>

Comment: @VBSlover That only matters if you need to differentiate from ones inside `td` and ones outside `td`. If that is not the case, this answer will work just as well. :)

Comment: Not that is not the case, I just need to collect such `href` values for further calculations and your code will help me in that regard!

Comment: `+1` to you,if possible please give me also something,although you gave a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

doesn't this do the trick?

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print a['href']
```

if you need you can use attrs in `find_all`:

```
soup.find_all("div", {"style": "display:inline; position:relative;"})
```

to strip whitespace and make the link absolute:

```
import urlparse
urlparse.urljoin(url, a['href'].strip())
```

Comment: Yeah! I used but couldn't clear the spaces embedded to those and also add with them `https://xyz.test.com/` to make it a complete `url`.

Comment: According to http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names the method name is `find_all`, not `findAll`